# Blender Bone deforming mesh when rotated

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I'm new on Blender and i wanted to make a 3D model and animate it, but when i put the armature and linked it to the model, and then tried to move the head in pose mode, it makes this weird thing and the head is kind of flatted... I verified every vertex group, and only the "head" one is linked to the head, and the entire head. I looked on a lot of forums and youtube videos but didn't see anything that could help me... someone have an idea? =c

Thanks in advance for your help...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Moving the head with the bone in pose mode on the Z-axis

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first thing I would try: From your last picture where the head verts are selected: With the Head group selected and weight at 1.0 click **Assign**. Then select each of the other vertex groups in turn and click **Remove**

Comment: I already did that, and retry again but it didn't change anything, the head still have the same problem =/ ...

Comment: The other thing I could think of is you used bone envelopes when you parented the mesh to the armature. Try unparenting the mesh, and adding an armature modifier to it instead of parenting? Make sure the modifier is set to group weights not bone envelopes

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That didn't work too, but i finally found WHAT is the real problem (and i feel stupid). Even if the model was in scale 1:1:1, the armature wasn't scale on 1:1:1, and that simply deformed the model. Thank you for help anyway =) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that happen to you, verify your model is scale on 1:1:1, but most importantly, that the ARMATURE is scale on 1:1:1 too ! It fixed my problem, so I can close the topic.

[image]